# Average and Inner Join in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, average

I'm very new to SQL thus why i ask this question. I'm trying to work out the average delivery time for items that have DO and DO NOT have a warranty. The warranty can be presented as either 1 or NaN so the column is not a NUMERIC.
I've written what I think the code should look like but come across errors.

#### SHIPPING_TABLE:

(Composite key)

```
Item_id
Basket_id
seller_id
warranty
postage_class
```

#### FIRST_CLASS:

(all as a primary key)

```
Item_id
Basket_id
seller_id
warranty
postage_class
delivery_time
```

---

```
create table AVG_DELIVERY_TIME as 
(
    SELECT DELIVERY_TIME AVG 
    ,(DELIVERY_TIME) 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT SHIPPING_TABLE_LINK.warranty
        ,FIRST_CLASS.DELIVERY_TIME
        FROM FIRST_CLASS
        INNER JOIN SHIPPING_TABLE_LINK 
            ON SHIPPING_TABLE_LINK.warranty = FIRST_CLASS.DELIVERY_TIME
    )
);
```

> Error report - ORA-01722: invalid number 01722. 00000 - "invalid number" *Cause: The specified number was invalid. *Action: Specify a valid number.

Comment: Your shipping and first class tables are almost identical, minus a few columns.  I propose that you consolidate them to a single table, and then add a column for the shipping type (it will be first class or some other rate).  Beyond this, tell us what database you are using, and tell us what the error is.

Comment: I am using oracle sql and the error is:                                          
create table AVG_DELIVERY_TIME as ( 
SELECT DELIVERY_TIME AVG ,(DELIVERY_TIME) FROM (SELECT SHIPPING_TABLE_LINK.warranty,
FIRST_CLASS.DELIVERY_TIME 
FROM FIRST_CLASS 
INNER JOIN SHIPPING_TABLE_LINK ON SHIPPING_TABLE_LINK.warranty = FIRST_CLASS.DELIVERY_TIME))
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Can you include your create table statement for these tables; i.e. showing the types of the columns?  The issue is likely that some column types are text and some are numeric.

Comment: Yes the warranty is a VARCHAR datatype as it can be represented by 1 or NaN.

Comment: My memory on Oracle is a little rusty, but I think you cannot CREATE a table from a select. What you can is to INSERT into a non-existing table from a SELECT, and this will result in the creation of the table plus the contents. Again, not 100% sure, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can update the values in your warranty column to be 0 rather than NaN by using the following code

UPDATE table_name
SET warranty = 0
WHERE warranty ="NaN;

you can then create your new table and specify this column as numeric rather than varchar. Hope that helps

Comment: `warrenty = NULL` would be better to indicate `NaN` (Not a Number)